# stripe-android using Eclipse and gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, stripe-payments

I have this **gradle file** (this is the entire file):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

  repositories {
   jcenter() 
}

   dependencies {
     compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:5.0.0'
}

}
```

I'm running '**gradle build**' and it's building, but in my java files I can't reference the new library. I'm adding this line to the source (java) file:
**`import com.stripe.android`**
I get this error: "The import com.stripe.android cannot be resolved"

Comment: please post at least one java file where you try to reference new library's classes, possibly post entire build.gradle and the error message you get when you try to reference lib's classes

Comment: I edited the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the problem is happened because the library is not supporting for Eclipse usage anymore.

From the [documentation excerpt](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/):

> Eclipse
>
> Note - as Google has stopped supporting Eclipse for Android
>   Development, we will no longer be actively testing the project's
>   compatibility within Eclipse. You may still clone and include the
>   library as you would any other Android library project.

So, you need to clone and include the library manually or migrate your code to Android Studio.

Comment: The library knows if I'm using Eclipse or Android Studio? Shouldn't it work as long as I use Gradle?

Comment: No, not the library. It means that stripe library is not tested for eclipse usage. It probably could works. But for a library related tightly with a security system, we should always use an actively tested library.